# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()' But I have the newest of all Android Studio, gradle,

Tags: android, android-studio

I just want implementation `'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'` to make image round. But I can't

I try update all things

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited the wrong `build.gradle` file. The lines right below your addition warn you against doing this:

```
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

If you have a typical Android Studio project, move your `implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'` from where you have it to the `dependencies` closure in the `app/build.gradle` file.